# Setting up Cookies at browser : Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, go

As am newbie here on Golang, trying to setup cookies at browser,
have simple basic code but it doesn't working at all & did some googling & found some stackoverflow ex. but still not picking up the right way.

Created a simple `hello.go`

```
package main

import "io"
import "net/http"
import "time"

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    expire := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    cookie := http.Cookie{"test", "tcookie", "/", "www.dummy.com", expire, expire.Format(time.UnixDate), 86400, true, true, "test=tcookie", []string{"test=tcookie"}}
    req.AddCookie(&cookie)
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}
```

But as expected here am facing error's like `\hello.go:9:15: composite struct literal net/http.Cookie with untagged fields`

Could any one please suggest me or give me basic example (in detailing) for setting up cookies.

Had few searches on SO and found..
[Setting Cookies in Golang (net/http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130582/setting-cookies-in-golang-net-http/12130619#12130619) but not able to picking up this properly..

Thanks.

Comment: @stephanos: Yeh, am aware about this, but not able to use that either, Could you please explore that in details, Would really appreciate your reply on this...

Comment: Try http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions with the default cookie back end.

Comment: Yes Trying that.... but how to import online packages on my local machine (Window 7 64bits), In Go SDK there is gopath folder.. downloaded three .go files which are require in this session.go but not able to add local path in import. Path of gopath folder is set in the environmental variable but still is is giving error of "failed parsing dir ", "not able to import from so so path"...etc.. ..What can be done ?

Comment: If your GOPATH is set correctly, just use `go get` as per the instructions. There is no need to download the files manually.

Comment: what version of go are you using ? type `go version`

Comment: @fabrizioM : go version go1.0.3 (appengine-1.8.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well in the question you link to it basically says to use this function from `net/http`:

```
func SetCookie(w ResponseWriter, cookie *Cookie)
```

So in your example instead of writing

```
req.AddCookie(&cookie)
```

you should write this

```
http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
```

Comment: Thanks, Still am getting same error, like `go-app-builder: Failed parsing input (1 error)` and `composite struct literal net/http.Cookie with untagged fields`

Comment: Am i missing some thing else here? Any guesses or idea about these error

Comment: Tried Full test program: from https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3033 link But on browser "404 page not found" this is displaying....

Answer (score 6):

`cookie := http.Cookie{"test", "tcookie", "/", "www.dummy.com", expire, expire.Format(time.UnixDate), 86400, true, true, "test=tcookie", []string{"test=tcookie"}}`

should be something like this:

`cookie := &http.Cookie{Name:"test", Value:"tcookie", Expires:time.Now().Add(356*24*time.Hour), HttpOnly:true}`

after this

change

`req.AddCookie(&cookie)`

to

`http.SetCookie(w, cookie)`

and finally because your application is running on Google App Engine change:

`func main()`

to

`func init()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also Replace that "func main()" to "func init()" .... Then it is Working.

Comment: you're welcome, it should not be required to change the `func main()` to `func init()`

Comment: @Neo for Google App Engine you need to use `func init()` instead of `func main()`. A bit outside the question, but OP is on Google App Engine as you can see from the tagging of the question...just a detail.