# Cookie can't be set.

Tags: go, cookies

I defined two handler functions, setCookie and getCookie.
The first function, setCookie, is called by getting access to localhost:8080/set_cookie, and then sends a HTTP response including two cookies.
The other function, getCookie, is called by accessing to localhost:8080/get_cookie, and then gets Cookie object.
I expect getCookie function to show information about two cookies, but a message, "first_cookie is not set successfully", is shown on a web browser.

Do you have any idea solving this problem?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "setCookie called")
    c1 := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "first_cookie",
        Value:    "Go Web App",
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    c2 := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "second_cookie",
        Value:    "Another service",
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    http.SetCookie(w, &c1)
    http.SetCookie(w, &c2)
}

func getCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "getCookie called")
    c1, err := r.Cookie("first_cookie")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "first_cookie is not set successfully.")
    }
    ca := r.Cookies()
    fmt.Fprintln(w, c1)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, ca)
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/set_cookie", setCookie)
    http.HandleFunc("/get_cookie", getCookie)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Cookies in Golang (net/http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130582/setting-cookies-in-golang-net-http)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your debugging statement...

```golang
fmt.Fprintln(w, "setCookie called")
```

... occurs before your `http.SetCookie` call.

Cookies are set in headers but by writing to the `http.ReponseWriter` you've triggered the completion of setting any headers. If you move the debug statement to the last line of `setCookie`, it will work as expected.

You can trivially test this by running:

```sh
curl -v -c "cookie.jar" "http://localhost:8080/set_cookie"
```

before and after such a change.

Comment: From the docs for `SetCookie`: "Changing the header map after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers."